# updating an Access 2010 Linked Table connection

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-connection, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

How do I change the connection string of a linked table in Access 2010? I don't want to do it programmatically but through the interface. When I try to change it via the table's Properties I get the following message:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the connection of one or more linked tables by using the "Linked Table Manager" on the "External Data" tab:

[image: LinkedTableManager.png]